# What is a recommended Docker Image to use for Adobe ColdFusion production environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, docker, coldfusion

I am not familiar with Adobe ColdFusion but one of my customer is contemplating hosting ColdFusion in AWS or Azure PaaS environment. I am thinking about using Docker container image for Adobe ColdFusion. But I could not find the certified docker image on DockerHub from Adobe for ColdFusion. Does anyone has any recommendation on how to containerize the Adobe ColdFusion using docker and if there is any certified docker image available?

Comment: Second result on https://qwant.com when typing "coldfusion docker images" => [Docker images for coldfusion](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/using/docker-images-coldfusion.html). The first result is a blog post referencing that page. And the first link on that page brings you to their [bintray repository](https://bintray.com/eaps/coldfusion)

Comment: They don't appear to be from hub.docker.com. Some of my Enterprise customer will not trust images from https://bintray.com/ as they have never heard it. Typically enterprise grade docker images from source are available in docker hub and companies trust this repos.

Comment: I agree with @Zeitounator  it doesn't get better than the original documentation and  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/using/docker-images-coldfusion.html comes up first when you search through google.

Comment: Well then you have to explain to your customers that these are the official images from adobe. So if they don't want to trust the editor, they should definitely switch technology. And I sure hope they don't want to later use anything from Elastic Search, Kibana, RedHat, testcontainers (and the list can be really long....) as they will also have to use an other tier registry for this.

Comment: Have you considered Lucee https://hub.docker.com/r/lucee/lucee?

Comment: @RodrigoM Can you share any information or article on how it can be used for hosting Adobe CF? I am sorry but I do not have any background in ColdFusion.

Comment: Sure @Andy Start with https://lucee.org/ in general, then have a look https://www.rasia.ch/blog/lucee-only-rational-choice-for-cfml-docker.html